# Is it possible to launch winform for the current console use from windows service

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a windows service that will monitor and update an app (winform) and if it's stops or it's not running should start it. But it should run the app as current console user. 
My problem it's that it starts the form with network service credentials so it's unavailable for the current user.

```
     protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (!GetProcessList())
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);
            StartProcces();

        }
        else 
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Process is running");
        }
    }

    void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartProcces();
    }
    static void StartProcces() 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + "\\WmiMonClient.exe");
        myProcess.WorkingDirectory = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

        //set environment path           
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myProcess);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }
    private static bool GetProcessList()
    {
        bool proccesIsRunning = false;
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
        {
            if (theprocess.ProcessName == "WmiMonClient.exe") 
            {
                proccesIsRunning = true;
            }
        }
        return proccesIsRunning;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to attack this might be to create a Scheduled Task (using Windows Scheduler) that executes your code above.  If it does, it just starts it up again.

This has the advantage of already running the user context, and not having to consider that from a windows service.